# How to set timezone of google calendar event using location and date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Sheet that people use to input information about events that happen throughout the world. The information they enter includes a date, start time, end time, and address. Location, date, and start time can be used to determine the timezone of the event but, so far as I can tell, there's no way to just tell the Google Calendar (via the UI or API) to automatically set the timezone based on that information. If you know of a way to get the API to do that, I'd love to know about it. Alternatively, I can use the Timezone API (part of the Maps API) to calculate the timezone based on that info. I'm having difficulty finding references that talk about how to do this with Google App Script though. Could you provide references or example code for performing this task? Thanks!

Comment: A users calendar is automatically set to their timezone.  You don't need to set the time zone of the user's calendar to get the date and time in their calendar to be adjusted to their time zone.  You haven't stated who owns the calendar.  You or the user?   There are 3 different time zones in this situation 1) The spreadsheet 2) The script 3) The calendar  Each one of those has it's own timezone setting.  Any date methods used by JavaScript in Apps Script converts the time zone to the time zone in the script project.  In a situation like this, I set the script time zone to 00:00

Comment: There is no point in having the script time zone set to your time zone.  If the script time zone is set to 00:00 then any differences are the offset.  It's easier to make sense of the time zone differences.  In the code editor choose: File -> Project Properties -> Time Zone GMT+00:00  If the spreadsheet is share among people in many times zones, I'd also set the time zone of the spreadsheet to GMT+00:00

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood, I think there's a misunderstanding. I want the calendar event to have the timezone of the event location (for the specified date). So, I'm on the east coast, and the spreadsheet has information for an event in September in San Francisco. I want the event to have the timezone of PDT.

Comment: You'll need to get the offset between their time and your time, and add / or subtract the offset from their date / time.  So, for example if the time that the user entered is 8 am, and in your time zone the same time is 4 am your time, then it will show up in your calendar as 4am.  You can get the timezone offset with `Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone , "Z")`  The problem is, you need some way to get the timezone of the user's location.  If they are using a spreadsheet of calendar that they own, from their account, and you have access to it, you can get their timezone that way.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood. Again, the point isn't to get the user's timezone. It's to get the timezone of location of the event which is listed in the document. Google has a Timezone service that will provide this information. It doesn't seem that that service is available to App Script though.

Comment: Are you talking about this:  [Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro)  If so, it looks like it will work with a REST Request, which can be made with Apps Script `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that. Good idea! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try.